# Is it possible to create these in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, modeling

I came across these artworks by Jacksachs and I've been wanting to create something similar for a while. Is it possible to create these effects using Photoshop, or do I need to play around with Blender?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This question is kinda broad. Depends on what you have and can already. You are asking how to create "these effects". It's not just effects. It's modeled in 3D and the gradients come from the materials and lighting setup. Some of the objects are transparent and some of them emits light. You could make something similar in Blender and then probably finalize in Photoshop.

Comment: Everything is possible if you invest enough time: just look at hyper-realism paintings. I think the more interesting question is not '*is it possible to create using Photoshop?*' but '*is it convenient to create using Photoshop?*' and the answer depends on what you want to do with these images.

Comment: In 3d most of these effects you're getting for free (I'm not talking about figuring out composition, color, etc now, just the physics), in Photoshop you'll have to understand how light reflection and refraction works, paint manually all the repeating elements... 10 minutes in Blender: https://i.imgur.com/FYrMXvd.png

Comment: Jack Sachs is a 3d animator and illustrator, so that image was probably done in 3D modelling software, not Photoshop.  His [website](https://www.jacksachs.co.uk/) has many examples of 3D renders and animations. Although he does also have some 2D illustration work on his site, the style is very different.

Answer (score 5):

Everything which is rendered in 3D can be also drawn in 2D if one can imagine the wanted result and has enough time and patience to put it together.

Making it simpler helps. The next example has only few details:

[image]

The green gloss is drawn, everything else is filled selections, blur, transparency and layer style effects. The most difficult part "the ability to imagine it" is skipped totally, it was in the question.